# How to verify if an extended attribute exist?

Tags: macos, extended-attributes

When running

```
 xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/XXX.app
```

sometimes I get

```
 xattr: /Applications/XXX.app: No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine
```

How does one verify if any named attribute exist for a given XXX.app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following `xattr` *command* causes both the attribute names and corresponding values to be displayed, if any exist.

```
xattr -l file
```

You can also use the `ls` *command*:

```
ls -@ file
```

---

That said, the `... No such xattr: com.apple.quarantine` message is a non-fatal message, meaning there's no real need to make it conditional, and if your goal is to remove the `com.apple.quarantine` *extended attribute* from a lot of files at once in a given *directory*, then `cd` to the target *directory* and use the following *command*:

```
for f in *; do xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine "$f" 2>/dev/null; done
```

The above one-liner will delete the `com.apple.quarantine` *extended attribute* off every file that has this and act as if the entire contents of the directory recursively were also specified (so that every file in the directory tree is acted upon), thats the `-r` *option*, while not showing errors for files that don't have the target *extended attribute*. (That's what the `2>/dev/null` does.)

Comment: I dunno about the non-fatal error. When I run `xattr` from the command prompt (bash), I get the message about "No such xattr", and, importantly for the context in which I'm working, the exit code is 1 (as displayed by `echo $?` immediately following). `xattr` is being executed in a series of commands (by `make`) and if the exit status for any command is not 0 (0 being the conventional "OK" exit status), the whole thing stops. So it would be ideal to avoid executing `xattr -d` if it's not needed. For the record I'm working on macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to test the existance of a specific extended attribute. In your case you could, with

```
file=/path/to/file
attr=attribute
```

do something like

```
if [[ $(xattr "$file") = *$attr* ]]; then
    xattr -d $attr "$file"
fi
```

or, as a one-liner

```
[[ $(xattr "$file") = *$attr* ]] && xattr -d $attr "$file"
```